# Android Studio Upload Button and Submit button in 1

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello guys basically I'm having trouble converting 2 of my buttons into 1.
I have a button for uploading an image into a database and another one for the data's also to the database.
Here's my code:

```
public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://animotradings.000webhostapp.com/upload.php";
public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";

//Categories Spinner
Spinner spinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

//Meet-up Spinner
Spinner spinner2;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sell_activityy);

    //PhotoUpload
    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Categories Spinner
    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(sCategories);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.category_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    // Meet-up Spinner
    spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(smeetup);
    adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.meetup_location, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    final EditText etItemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etItemName);
    final EditText etCondition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCondition);
    final EditText etDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDescription);
    final EditText etPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPrice);
    final EditText etContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etContact);
    final Spinner sCategories  = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.sCategories);
    final Spinner smeetup = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.smeetup);
    final Button bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);

    bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String item_name = etItemName.getText().toString();
            final String conditionn = etCondition.getText().toString();
            final String description = etDescription.getText().toString();
            final int price = Integer.parseInt(etPrice.getText().toString());
            final double contact = Double.parseDouble(etContact.getText().toString());
            final String categories = sCategories.getSelectedItem().toString();
            final String meetup = smeetup.getSelectedItem().toString();


            // Data Upload...
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success){
                            Intent intent =  new Intent(SellActivityy.this, NavigationDrawer.class);
                            SellActivityy.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SellActivityy.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Ad posting failed!")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            SellRequest sellRequest = new SellRequest(item_name, conditionn, description, price, contact, categories, meetup, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SellActivityy.this);
            queue.add(sellRequest);
        }
    });
}

//PhotoUpload

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private Button buttonView;

private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
private void uploadImage(){
    // Picture Upload...
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(SellActivityy.this, "Uploading...", null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();

            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);

            return result;
        }
    }

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
    ui.execute(bitmap);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }

   if(v == buttonUpload){
       uploadImage();
   }



private void viewImage() {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, ImageListView.class)); }}
```

I have tried transferring the code inside bsubmit.onclicklistener and have also tried altering the codes for the submit and upload buttons, but so far no success.
Sorry for the noob question guys, I'm actually new to Android Studio and is having trouble adapting.
I will keep on trying different codes and maybe start from scratch, but if you guys could help me, it would be great. Thanks :D

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: not able to figure out your problem nor your requirement

Comment: Basically, I have 2 buttons, one for uploading a picture and one for the data's both to be uploaded in a database.
I'm trying to convert that 2 buttons to only 1 so that when i click the button, i will be able to upload both the picture and the data's in the database simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your bSubmit.onClickListener(), just add

```
buttonUpload.performClick();
```

This will mimic a button press on the upload button and will perform it's task.

Comment: I tried this but it's only uploading the picture, not the data's.